# undefined reference to library function in Qtcreator

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, hyperlink

I have to use a library under Linux. It's a .so compiled with gcc.

I added on my .pro :

```
INCLUDEPATH += mypath/include
LIBS += -L/mypath/lib/ -lmyLib
```

but, i get the following error :

```
undefined reference to `init_glove(char*, char*)'
```

I don't understand why i get this message. My library is linked and the header file is founded. I read that it could be a problem between the compiler used for my library, and the one used by Qt, but both seem to be gcc, so...

Any ideas ?

Comment: They might be different versions of GCC. The w32 port seems to have ABI changes between releases, and that means you can't link libraries compiled with a different version.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem was the g++/gcc issue, then in your QT project simply do this

```
extern "C"
{
   #include "mylib.h"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Qt was compiling with g++, so I had to change de compiler of my library : switching it from gcc to g++.